# Disable loading of initialRoute inside stack navigator when

Tags: react-native, axios, react-navigation

I have two stacks in my react-native app similar to this structure. When I navigate a user from `Home` screen inside `MainStack` to `Quiz` screen inside `QuizStack`, the `componentDidMount` method of `QuizList` screen is being called. How do I prevent this? I want only the `componentDidMount` of `Quiz` screen to be called.

```
export const MainStack = createStackNavigator({
    Home: { screen: Home },
    Game: { screen: Game },
    Leaderboard: { screen: Leaderboard }
}, { initialRouteName: 'Home' })

export const QuizStack = createStackNavigator({
    QuizList: { screen: QuizList },
    Quiz: { screen: Quiz },
    QuizResult: { screen: QuizResult }
}, { initialRouteName: 'QuizList' })

export const InternalStacks = createBottomTabNavigator({
        QuizStack: { screen: QuizStack, navigationOptions: { tabBarLabel: 'Quiz' } },
        MainStack: { screen: MainStack, navigationOptions: { tabBarLabel: 'Home' } },
    })
```

What makers matters worse is, on sending a push notification, users are directed automatically from Home(MainStack) to Quiz (QuizStack). The componentDidMount method in Quiz calls an API, so if 10K users opens notifications, that 10K APIs called. Then unecesarily the componentDidMount method of QuizList(QuizStack) is also being called, which is an additional 10K APIs

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear to me why you have two separate stacks, and how they are connected. Maybe by a top level navigator? You should try to merge the stacks into a single one.

About the Push notification, you can create a SwitchNavigator:

```js
const SwitchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    Loading: LoadingScreen,
    Root: RootStack
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Loading'
  }
)
```

And in the componentDidMount in LoadingScreen, you will check the initial URL received by the push.

```js
async componentDidMount() {
    const { navigation } = this.props
    const initialURL = await Linking.getInitialURL()
    if (initialURL && initialURL.startsWith('myapp://myapp/xxx')) {
      navigation.navigate('MyScreenA', { options })
    } else {
      navigation.navigate('MyScreenDefaultScreen')
    }
  }
```

Comment: I have edited the question to include the ```createBottomTabNavigator``` that connects the both stackNavigators. Is it possible to achieve this by setting any lazy property rather than having a separate loading screen?

Comment: About the call to `componentDidMount` in `QuizList`, in `QuizStack`, you can reorder the screens and put `Quiz` first, same for the `initialRoute`.

Comment: Then tab navigator will set it as the default tab. They should see the QuizList on navigating via tab navigator, but go to Quiz screen when opening notificaiton without calling did mount of QuizList